# add files to target xcode through command line

Tags: ios, xcode, cmd, xcodebuild

I can build xcode project through command line using `xcodebuild`. I want to add files to project before building, currently I drag and drop files to project and while I do that it add to project as well. Other option is 'right click' and 'add files to project'

But how to add files through command line? `cp` command doesn't add files to project/target.

Comment: I would recommend you file an enhancement request with Apple if you think you have a good use case for this.

Comment: found a work around I created reference to files I want to add and update those files. Since it's a reference it takes updated files